# What is 'get()' function appeared in profiling on Python (PyPy)?

Tags: python, pypy

I profile my program by 'profile.py' on PyPy 1.8.

```
import profile
profile.run('run()', filename)
import pstats
p = pstats.Stats(filename)
p.sort_stats('time').print_stats(10)
```

Here is output of profiling:

```
Fri May 25 06:40:26 2012    profile.output

         225308 function calls (220308 primitive calls) in 1832700302271.964 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 49 to 10 due to restriction <10>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    57000 15986440103363.266 280463861.463 15986440103363.266 280463861.463 :0(get)
     7000 5696817988322.265 813831141.189 5696817988322.265 813831141.189 :0(getattr)
     .....
```

This result shows that 'get()' is the bottlenecks of program.
But I don't know 'get()' function at all.

What is 'get()' function on Python?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but I can't understand your intension. I'm not native English speaker nor good at English. Could you explain what you say in easy English? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, Levon. I understand the rule of stackoverflow. I checked the answer below. And your English is easy for me to understand :) Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a dictionary is used somewhere in the code being profiled.

```
get(key[, default])

Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. 
If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method 
never raises a KeyError.
```

See [Mapping Types - dict](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) and [Python dictionary get() Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm).

Comment: Great! This is the answer what I want. Of course, I know dict.get(), but profiling output doesn't remind me of it. Thank you very much.